# prints the ASM code to generate the given class Usage: ASMifier [-debug] <fully qualified class name or class file name>

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

my os is Ubuntu 16.04
I code java on eclipse neon (my jdk is openjdk I couldn't download jdk from oracle)
it doesn't depend on code .wether I code a helloworld program or a complex one I would have problem with this error below
"prints the ASM code to generate the given class Usage: ASMifier [-debug] "

by the way before this I had problem with this error
"the selection can not be launched, and there are no recent launches"
then I used configure run and introduced a library to my main after that the error I wrote in my title happened.
thanks for reading my problems

Comment: Have you googled that error message? Where is it showing up? In eclipse, or when you run javac or java on the command line?

Comment: I had googled it once and I found nothing.even I searched youtube ,and again I found nothing.the error shows up in eclipse.thanks for your answering

Answer (score 1):

You are running the program as "Run as Asmifier " changed it to the Run as "Java application" in eclipse while executing the program to execute the program successfully.